# Dynamically Added Button eventListener

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dynamic, event-listener

I have code where I need to take an ArrayList of data (returned from a SQLite database) and convert it to a table via the code below. What I was wondering is how I would go about adding a clickListener to the button I add dynamically to the table? Basically it would add the value from one of the columns in the row into a SharedPreference variable that I access elsewhere.

Please let me know if more information is needed, but I think that makes sense.

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(TabFragment3.this.getActivity());
List<FoodPoints> foodpoints = db.getAllFoodPoints();

    for (FoodPoints fp : foodpoints) {
        String listFood = fp.getFood();
        String listPoints = Integer.toString(fp.getPoints());
        String listDate = fp.getDate();

        listDate = listDate.substring(0, 12);

        insertRow(tablePoints, listFood, listPoints, listDate);
        // String log = "ID: " + fp.getID() + ", Food: " + fp.getFood() + ", Points: " + fp.getPoints() + ", Date: " + fp.getDate();
        // Log.d("FoodPoints", log);
    }

private void insertRow(TableLayout tablePoints, String tblFoodName, String tblFoodPoints, String tblFoodDate) {
    final TableRow newrow = new TableRow(currentActivity);

     addPlusButtonPointsTable(newrow);
    addTexttoRowswithValues(newrow, tblFoodName, 3);
    addTexttoRowswithValues(newrow, tblFoodPoints, 17);
    addTexttoRowswithValues(newrow, tblFoodDate, 17);
    tablePoints.addView(newrow);
}

...

private void addPlusButtonPointsTable(TableRow newrow) {
    Button plusButton = new Button(currentActivity);
    //plusButton.setBackgroundColor(R.drawable.);
    plusButton.setText("+");
    plusButton.setMinimumWidth(1);
    plusButton.setMinimumHeight(1);
    plusButton.setTextSize(14);

    newrow.addView(plusButton);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the `addPlusButtonPointsTable()` method to also take the value of the column(for example the food name) that you would like to store in the preferences when the `Button` is clicked clicked(I think this is what you want no?) like this:

```java
private void addPlusButtonPointsTable(TableRow newrow, String foodName) {
    // ...
    // set the data as the tag for the Button
    plusButton.setTag(foodName);
    plusButton.setOnClickListener(mListener);
    // ...
}
```

This method will be called like this:

```java
addPlusButtonPointsTable(newrow, tblFoodName);
```

The `mListener` is like this:

```java
OnClickListener mListener = new OnCLickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         String foodName = (String)v.getTag();
         // store the value.
     }
}
```

I would also recommend that you use the proper `LayoutParams`  when adding the views to the `TableRow` and the `TableRow`  to the `TableLayout`.

When adding the views to the `TableRow`:

```java
newrow.addView(plusButton, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

When adding the `TableRow` to the `TableLayout`:

```java
tablePoints.addView(newrow, new Tablelayout.LayoutParams(Tablelayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Tablelayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

If you support versions below 2.2 use `FILL_PARENT` instead of `MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: May I ask what you mean by using the proper LayoutParams when adding views to TableRow and TableLayout?

Comment: Ah okay thank you - this may be why I was getting a formatting issue when adding rows to my table.

Answer (score 1):

In your `addPlusButtonPointsTable()` method add this line:

```
plusButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do what you want
    }
});
```

Comment: And this is before I add the Button to the TableRow? I had a feeling it was that easy, but I wasn't 100% sure if it was.

Comment: it doesn't matter when you do this as long as it is below the `new Button()` call.